# How to redirect abseil logging messages to stout instead of stderr?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, stdout, abseil, absl-py

I am using `python` `3.7.6`. and abseil module for logging messages `with absl-py` `0.9.0`. I am using this piece of code for my tests.

```
from absl import logging
from absl import app

def main(argv):

    #logging.set_stderrthreshold(logging.ERROR)
    #logging._warn_preinit_stderr = False
    logging.set_verbosity(logging.DEBUG)

    print(' 0 -----')
    logging.debug(' 1 logging-debug-test')
    logging.info(' 2 logging-info-test')
    logging.warning(' 3 logging-warning-test')
    logging.error('4 logging-error-test')
    print(' 5 -----')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)
```

When testing it in a `Jupyter notebook`, it is clear from the color code of the background that abseil messages are in the stderr stream.

[image]

Same things when executing the python code in a shell:
[image]
[image]
I tried few things with different values like:

```
logging.set_stderrthreshold(logging.DEBUG)
logging._warn_preinit_stderr = True
```

but I still see 100% the same output.

- How can I redirect output abseil logging messages to stdout instead of stderr ?
- Is it expected to have the logging output messages redirect to stderr and not stdout? I am probably missing something with the logging logic and I want to better understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was told that this is the standard behavior and what Python's standard logging module does. In my case adding the following line redirect the logging messages to stdout:

```
logging.get_absl_handler().python_handler.stream = sys.stdout
```

Now in my Jupyter notebook it looks like that:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use both `sys.stdout` in addition to a logging file? Can't seem to hack it myself...

Answer (score -1):

This did NOT work for me for some reason:

```
from absl import logging
import sys

logging.get_absl_handler().python_handler.stream = sys.stdout
```

But this did:

```
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout)
```